# Getting qualified method name by the line number

Tags: java, maven, compiler-construction, abstract-syntax-tree, fully-qualified-naming

This question is Java and Maven specific. Please note the additional constraints below as they are different from other questions.

I have several Maven (Java) projects to analyze. What I have is:

- the source code
- maven-compiled Jave code with binaries in target/ folder

The question is:
Given one source code file (.java) and a line number there, how can I get the **fully qualified name of the method** that spans over that line? If the line is not in a method then just output null. Acceptable languages to implement this are: Java, ruby, or python.

Could you please answer the question in one of the following two ways?

1. use the binary and extract **qualified** method name of that line. (This might involve weave in debug info, but that is fine.)
2. directly use the source file given, try to parse it and use the AST.

Using specific libraries (like BCEL) or any 3rd party ones (as long as they are well documented and usable) are OK, too.

Many many thanks for the huge help!

Comment: Since the source code is not guaranteed compilable, it may be impossible, besides the line number may not be in a method at all.

Comment: Hmmm, OK yes, let me make it compilable for sure then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, your question is full of drawbacks:

- You could, of corse, parse the input source (through an Javacc or ANTLR parser) until you reach the desired line. But it seems a waste of effort to parse the same source since you already have the `.class` files.
- So, it seems better to analyze the `.class` file. But unfortunately, you have no gurantee that this is the class where your line spawns at, because there can be *more than one class* defined in the same source file.

Augh! That leads me to a kind of complicated solution:

I'll declare a class which will contain all the login:

```
public class SourceMethodsIndexer
{
    private final SortedMap<Integer, List<Method>> indexOfMethodsByFirstLineNumber;
}
```

The constructor will be like this:

```
public SourceMethodsIndexer(File sourceFile)
```

... and should do these tasks:

1.Browse the class directory related to the target package.

```
File targetPackageDir=getTargetPackageDir(sourceFile);
File[] classFiles=targetPackageDir.listFiles(new FileFilter(){
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name){
        return name.endsWith(".class");
}
```

});

2.Use Apache BCEL to collect all the non public classes belonging to your input source file (you can invoke `JavaClass.getSourceFileName()` to filter classes), plus the public class corresponding to the name of your input source file.

```
Collection<JavaClass> targetClasses=getNonPublicClasses(classFiles, sourceFile.getName());
targetClasses.add(publicClass);
```

3.Collect then all the methods in each class.

```
Set<Method> targetMethods=new HashSet<Method>(1024);
for (JavaClass javaClass:targetClasses)
{
    targetMethods.addAll(Arrays.asList(javaClass.getMethods()));
}
```

4.Now you can either search directly your line number, or index first the methods by line number to access them later more quickly: `JavaClass.getMethods()[n].getLineNumberTable().getSourceLine(0)` (take care that there could be repeated values).

```
this.indexOfMethodsByFirstLineNumber=new TreeMap<Integer, List<Method>>((int)(1.7d*methods.size()));
for (Method method: methods)
{
    // Note: The -1 in this line stands to make the SortedMap work properly when searching for ranges.
    int firstLine=getLineNumberTable().getSourceLine(0)-1;
    List<Method> methodsInTheSameLine=indexOfMethodsByFirstLineNumber.get(firstLine);
    if (methodsInTheSameLine==null)
    {
        methodsInTheSameLine=new ArrayList<Method>();
        indexOfMethodsByFirstLineNumber.put(firstLine,methodsInTheSameLine);
    }
    methodsInTheSameLine.add(method);
}
```

5.Public a method to do the search:

```
public Method getMethodByLine(int lineNumber)
{
    Set<Method> methodsInTheSameLine=this.indexOfMethodsByFirstLineNumber.headMap(lineNumber).lastKey();
    if (methodsInTheSameLine.size()==0)
    {
        // There are no methods method in that line: Absurd.
    }
    else if (methodsInTheSameLine.size()>1)
    {
        // There are more than one method in that line. Hardly probable, but possible.
    }
    else
    {
        // There is one method in that line:
        return methods.get(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Little. This answer is very close to what I need. Would you mind elaborating your answer a little bit? I see that you have about 4 steps there, but just for the last one, what is the way to directly search the line number? You can assume that the debug information is in the byte code.

Comment: Of corse: I've updated my answer with further details of my proposal. The methods I've just named and not implemented I deem them simple enough.

Comment: I think this is good enough as an answer from the angle of inspecting into byte code generated. I ended up parsing the AST and get its fully qualified name, though. As promised, let me accept this answer to reward your help. Thanks, Little.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of open source Maven plugins which analyse source code, and report on a per-method basis. A careful study of some of those may be your best bet.

Examples include Checkstyle, FindBugs, PMD, JDepend, JavaNCSS.

Also take a look at SonarQube.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, Stewart.